# Why isn't this simple CRON job working?

Tags: server, php, cron

I am on Ubuntu server and would like to send an email to myself every 10 minutes (as a test).

The code for that is in this file:

```
/var/www/cron-test.php
```

To set up the cron I typed:

```
crontab -e
```

and added this line to the bottom of the file using nano editor:

```
### email me every 10 min.
*/10 * * * * /var/www/cron-test.php
```

But that script is not running every 10 minutes. I only recieve the email if I load the PHP script directly in my browser. The cron doesn't seem to be executing at all.

What am I doing wrong?

Also this is my first time setting up a cron so putting the cron script in my www folder is probably not a good idea, should I put it elsewhere? If so where?

Also is there a cron error log? Where all failed crons can be seen?

Comment: You need to run it through PHP of course, php-files are not executable.

Comment: @Bobby I can run the script by navigating to /var/www and typing "php cron-test.php". How should I modify the cron command to tell it to run the script using the "php" command. Just by adding php before the path to the script?

Comment: @Bobby Ahh it works now. Just had to add php before the script path. Thanks for bringing it to my attention. If you post that as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stating the obvious:

```
*/10 * * * * php /var/www/cron-test.php
```

You might also need to write the full path to your php interpreter.